# Unexpected results with verified htaccess rewrite rules on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following **htaccess rewrite rules** in my httpd.conf in a virtualhost section (Apache). If the request is just `<filename>` without `<extension>`, Apache will evaluate from HTTP_ACCEPT in the request header which file to return. In the directory /images, there are only .avif, .webp and .jpeg files, one version for each filename.

```
<Directory "/var/www/<document root>/images">
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/avif 
    AddType image/avif .avif
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.avif [L] 

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
    AddType image/webp .webp
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.webp [L]

    AddType image/jpeg .jpeg
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.jpeg
</directory>
```

Thus, if a file isn't caught by the first two RewriteCond, it will receive the suffix .jpeg.

Testing this with https://htaccess.madewithlove.com returns exactly the expected results. And in the wild it works fine.

Now I've put a file with a different `<extension`> in the directory /images, called `dm_schrift.svg`. I would expect the request to be rewritten as dm_schrift.jpeg. Instead, the server returns the correct file:

```
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -D - https://<my domain>/images/dm_schrift.svg
HTTP/2 200
date: Thu, 08 Sep 2022 09:12:19 GMT
server: Apache
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
last-modified: Tue, 30 Aug 2022 18:30:12 GMT
etag: "356-5e779921d3500"
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 854
vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
cache-control: max-age=31536000, public, immutable
content-type: image/svg+xml
```

(Regarding 'immutable': I get the same result if opening a new browser window, disabling cache in DevTools, loading the file and verifing, that it actually gets downloaded. The response is not from cache).

How can it be that I receive the file and not 404 for dm_schrift.jpeg?

**EDIT:** the following was part of the question and has been addressed in an answer, but was based on wrong assumptions. To be waived:

> Another question regarding these rewrite rules: with these, a file
> requested as 'something' will be served as 'something.avif' in Chrome.
> Devtools/Network shows the whole name incl. extension. But the name
> wasn't included in the response header. That the file actually is
> 'avif' can be derived from the 'content-type', but how does the
> browser know the whole filename incl. extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would seem to have already answered your question in the opening paragraph...

> If the request is **just `<filename>` without `<extension>`**, Apache will evaluate...

And this follows the regex in your rules. ie. `^([^\.]+)$` (*Aside:* the backslash-escape on the literal dot is not required here.

You are requesting the actual file in your example, complete with file extension, eg. `/images/dm_schrift.svg`. The regex does not match so the rules do not apply, so the file is simply served directly.

> How can it be that I receive the file and not 404 for dm_schrift.jpeg?

This would only happen if you made the initial request *without* the file extension (as you stated initially).

> Devtools/Network shows the whole name incl. extension. But the name wasn't included in the response header. That the file actually is 'avif' can be derived from the 'content-type', but **how does the browser know the whole filename incl. extension?**

From the rules you've posted, the browser does *not* know the complete filename (including file extension) of the file on the server that is being rewritten to. The browser only knows the mime-type (ie. from the `Content-Type` header) - which doesn't really have anything to do with the file extension.

> I have the following htaccess rewrite rules in my httpd.conf in a virtualhost section (Apache).

Just to clarify, the rules you've posted are inside a `<Directory>` section (which is inside a virtualhost section). This is very different to when the rules are directly inside the virtualhost section itself, which would inferred from your description.

`<Directory>` sections behave just like `.htaccess`, but note that any `.htaccess` files will *override* the corresponding `<Directory>` section in the server config.

Comment: Thank you. My assumption was that the last rewrite rule for jpeg would be applied unconditionally, without a former positive RewriteCond, if the first two don't apply and the file "falls through". And now I tested and confirm this. I put another file 'dm_schrift.jpeg' in the directory and used curl to query for 'dm_schrift' without extension. It returned 200 dm_schrift.jpeg, with content-type 'image/jpeg'. Accordingly 'dm_schrift.svg' should not be matched, and <filename>-up-to-dot + '.jpeg' should be served. But still dm_schrift.svg is returned. So my question remains.

Comment: you are right about the showing of the full filename / extension in DevTools. I got that wrong, it's not shown. Gonna edit the question accordingly

Comment: @jamacoe "the last rewrite rule for jpeg would be applied unconditionally" - it's only applied when the regex (ie. `^([^\.]+)$`) successfully matches the requested URL-path (which it does not when you request a file _with_ an extension). "Accordingly 'dm_schrift.svg' should not be matched, and <filename>-up-to-dot + '.jpeg' should be served." (not "accordingly") `dm_schrift.svg` is not matched by any of your rules, so **the file is simply served directly**. The `.jpeg` file should _not_ be served (based on your rules).

Comment: @jamacoe If you wanted that last rule to essentially work _unconditionally_ then you would use `RewriteRule (.*) $1.jpeg` - which would result in `dm_schrift.svg` being rewritten to `dm_schrift.svg.jpeg`. OR, only grab the part of the URL-path before the extension (but still allow an extension on the initial request that is stripped). eg. `RewriteRule ^([^.]+) $1.jpeg` (note the `$` on the regex is removed). Now a request for `dm_schrift.svg` would be rewritten to `dm_schrift.jpeg` (the `.svg` extension is replaced).

Comment: True, the RewriteCond regEx is only for files without any dot. I had a better day when I put this together. It actually does what I want.